# TMRpcm not compatible incompatible with current board

Tags: arduino-nano, tmrpcm, arduino-nano-every

My goal is to play sounds with my Arduino Nano Every. I tried the example sketch that comes with the library but I get the error:

```
**WARNING: library TMRpcm-master claims to run on avr architecture(s) and may be incompatible with your current board which runs on megaavr architecture(s).**
```

Is there such a big difference between the Nano and Nano every?

Comment: All the peripherals (timers, comms, programming etc. etc) have changed so code which directly accesses hardware registers (say to configure a timer) may fail. Some libraries already have some compatibility. Others may never be updated. If you have to get the MCU data sheet out to solve low level device access/control issues, you'll find yourself in a new world. You could try opening an incompatibility issue for this particular library here: https://github.com/TMRh20/TMRpcm/issues

Answer (score 1):

I opened a issue on GitHub and the result is: tmrpcm only runs on avr architecture so it is incompatible with megaavr architecture(s).